# Opendistro Elasticsearch Azure repository plugin

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I've been trying to use azure blob storage with *opendistro elasticsearch* for snapshot. I've passed account name and key for storage account but while trying to register repo. getting following error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"repository_verification_exception","reason":"[bk] path  is not accessible on master node"}],"type":"repository_verification_exception","reason":"[bk] path  is not accessible on master node","caused_by":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":"Cannot invoke \"String.length()\" because \"host\" is null"}},"status":500}
```

also error on node

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoryVerificationException: [bk] path  is not accessible on master node
    at org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.startVerification(BlobStoreRepository.java:1276) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$3.doRun(RepositoriesService.java:268) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:743) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "host" is null
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.isHostDnsName(Utility.java:533) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.determinePathStyleFromUri(Utility.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageUri.<init>(StorageUri.java:71) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.PathUtility.appendPathToUri(PathUtility.java:124) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.PathUtility.appendPathToUri(PathUtility.java:108) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.<init>(CloudBlobContainer.java:169) ~[?:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient.getContainerReference(CloudBlobClient.java:123) ~[?:?]
```

Following is my custom docker image

```
FROM amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.13.0
RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch  repository-azure

ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT <bas64 encoded account>
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_KEY <base64 encoded key>

RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore create

RUN echo $AZURE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin azure.client.default.account
RUN echo $AZURE_CLIENT_KEY | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin azure.client.default.key
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Could you send the configuration file used on the master?

Comment: Updated my answer, i just have custom docker image and rest is default config